# python write lines that contain a pipe '|'

Tags: python, text

i wrote this program, and while it worked for whatever reason it wrote a few extra lines that i did not want. the file is 7199 records long and i only want the program to write the lines that contain a `'-'` in lines[3]:

im doing this by first excluding lines that 1) have a `/` then 2) finding lines that contain a `|` and finally writing the lines where there is a `-` in lines [3]:

here is the `lines` list:

`['4192614149', '48', '514', '2014-09-03', '', 'EXP0012']`

here is my program:

```
#!C:/Python27
pipe = '|'
dash = '-'
fslash = '/'
with open('O:/textdocs/exptest1.txt', 'rb') as f, open('O:/textdocs/exptest2.txt', 'ab') as n:
    for line in f:
        if fslash not in line:
            if pipe in line:
                lines = line.strip().split('|')
                if dash in lines[3]:
                    n.writelines('|'.join(lines) + '\n')
```

if i do not include `if fslash not in line:` the program sometimes writes the header `09/07/14  COMPANY NAME INC.    PAGE 1`. it doesnt do this when i test the program with a smaller file. i want to know if someone can re-write my code in a shorter/more efficient way.

thank you -jon

here is a sample of exptest1.txt:

```
   09/07/14  COMPANY NAME INC.    PAGE 1
    6:04 AM  JOB #PP100048023 *DO NOT EDIT

ACCOUNTS FOR MULTIPLE ITEMS


EXP ITEM
EXP PHONE #1
EXP PHONE #2
EXP PHONE #3
EXP PHONE #4
EXP PHONE #5
EXP PAY
EXP POSTPONE
EXP DEPT
EXP FWD
EXP DECEASE
EXP INCREASE
--------------------------------------------------
3693759155|48|514|2014-09-03||EXP0012 
3693759155|48||||EXP0012 
3693759155|48||||EXP0012 
3693759155|48||||EXP0012 
3693759155|48||||EXP0012 
3693759155|48||||EXP0012 
3693759155|48|516|2014-09-02||EXP0012 
3693759155|48||||EXP0012-1 
3693759155|48||||EXP0012-2 
3693759155|48||||EXP0012-3 
3693759155|48||||EXP0012-4 
3693759155|48||||EXP0012-5 
3070104114|48||||EXP0012 
3070104114|48|515|2014-09-04||EXP0012 
3070104114|48|515|2014-09-05||EXP0012 
3070104114|48||||EXP0012 
3070104114|48||||EXP0012 
3070104114|48||||EXP0012 
3070104114|48||||EXP0012 
3070104114|48||||EXP0012-1 
3070104114|48||||EXP0012-2 
3070104114|48||||EXP0012-3 
3070104114|48||||EXP0012-4 
3070104114|48||||EXP0012-5 
4192614149|48|514|2014-09-03||EXP0012 
4192614149|48||||EXP0012 
4192614149|48||||EXP0012 
4192614149|48||||EXP0012 
4192614149|48||||EXP0012 
4192614149|48||||EXP0012 
4192614149|48||||EXP0012 
4192614149|48||||EXP0012-1 
4192614149|48||||EXP0012-2 
4192614149|48||||EXP0012-3 
4192614149|48||||EXP0012-4 
4192614149|48||||EXP0012-5 

     ** END OF REPORT **
```

this sample shows the extra lines the code writes when i use the full original file of 7199 records if i dont include: `if fslash not in line:`. i do not know why it writes the header `09/07/14  COMPANY NAME INC.    PAGE 818` at random lines but its not a big deal as it excludes the header when i use `if fslash not in line:`

```
5311540025|48|515|2014-09-02||NG0005
5311540025|48|565|2014-09-05||NG0005-5 
   09/07/14  COMPANY NAME INC.    PAGE 818 # extra line **********
3110176249|48|515|2014-09-05||NG0012
1586526008|48|515|2014-09-05||NG0049
```

i want to *write* the lines that contain a dash `'-'` in lines[3] as below:

```
5311540025|48|515|2014-09-02||NG0005
5311540025|48|565|2014-09-05||NG0005-5
3110176249|48|515|2014-09-05||NG0012
1586526008|48|515|2014-09-05||NG0049
```

***again the program works, i just want to know if can be re-written in a more efficient way*****

Comment: It is hard to reason about your code.  For example, why do you test `if fslash not in line` at the very first thing for every line?

Comment: which extra lines does it print out?

Comment: because when i ran the code in the original file with 7199 records, it wrote the header `09/07/14  COMPANY NAME INC.    PAGE 1` at random lines. so i checked if line has a  `/` also

Comment: Anyway, I have an idea: You say you want only lines that “have a date `'-'`” but your code tests `if dash in lines[3]`.  You should probably test `if lines[3] == dash` instead?

Comment: You need to explain the difference between what you want and what you got; preferably by *showing* examples

Comment: @5gon12eder i dont think i can do `if lines[3] == dash` because that index includes other characters ie: `|2014-09-02|`

Comment: @Borodin i edited my original post with examples. thank you

Comment: Okay thank you. I can see why you added the test for a slash, but that line doesn't contain hyphens `-` or pipes `|` so it shouldn't be printed anyway.

Comment: You are opening the output file with mode `'ab'`, so for appending, could it be that the additional line has already been in the file *before* you ran the code?

Comment: @jes516 The sample you provided does not reproduce the issue , unless you provide the original file(put it some where and give the link to downlad ) it will be hard to point the problem just by looking at the code ...

Comment: You need to be specific about your requirements or nobody will be able to help you.  Do you want lines where the date *is* `'-'` or where it *contains a* `'-'`? Once you can write down your requirements in English, the Python code will be easy.

Comment: @5gon12eder i want the program to find the lines that contain a `'|'` pipe, then *write* the lines that contain a dash `'-'` in lines[3]. as i mentioned before, the code works but i want to see if it can be RE-WRITTEN in a more efficient/shorter way. hope this makes sense -jon

Comment: Well, your question has changed quite dramatically.  If the program now works correctly, I think you can be satisfied.  Your code does not look ugly and is not obviously inefficient.  If it ain't broke, don't fix it.